# Reinstalled Python, but suddenly it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I started with Anaconda on this computer, but I didn't like it, so I uninstalled and moved to just using Visual Studio Code. It worked for months. Suddenly I come to my laptop again (it's a WFH device and nobody interferes on my machine), and Python codes no longer work at all. The error I get is:

```
> & : The term 'C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start
> Menu/Programs/Python 3.9' is not recognized as the name of a  cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:3
> C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Progr ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/me...rams/Python
> 3.9:String) [], CommandNotFoundException FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

when I attempt to run my programs.

I have tried to fix the Python path in the bottom left of VSC, but no luck there. I did reinstall Python 3.9 (latest version) and I did definitely add to PATH.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The looks like the path to a folder rather than the program. If you can control it, I would strongly recommend that you not included spaces and periods in your paths.

Comment: I am actually just using the same Play button in VSC that I've used for months - it no longer works. My guess is, when I reinstalled, something important got unplugged/moved. Just not sure what that would be.